# Convert For Loop to List Comprehension: Testing if elements in list 2 are partial match for elements in list 1

Tags: python, list, for-loop, list-comprehension

somewhat of a python/programming newbie here,

I have come up with a code of 2 nested for loops to test if the elements of the the 2nd loop are a partial (or complete) match of the elements in the first list, and if so those elements are removed from the 1st list. Here is the code:

```
>>> lst = ["my name is Bob Jenkins", "Tommy Cooper I am", "I be Bazil", "I Tarzan"]
>>> names = ["Bob", "Tarzan"]
>>> for l in lst:
        for n in names:
            if n in l:
                lst.remove(l)


>>> print lst
['Tommy Cooper I am', 'I be Bazil']
```

The problem here is that I don't actual want to modify `lst`, but create a new list. Thus list comprehension raises its head. However, I have not been able to figure out a list comprehension to pull this off. I have tried `[i for i in lst for n in names if n not in i]` but this does not work. Of course the `.remove` method is not for list comprehension. I have been puzzling for the past hour, but cannot come up with anything.

Any ideas?

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, but a comment on your current solution: You should never modify a list (eg remove elements) while iterating through it. You can iterate through a copy of it though, eg:
for l in lst[:]:
   lst.remove(l)

Comment: I found all 3 answers (thus far) equally helpful, so I cannot choose between them as the best answer in that respect. However, I am going to accept darkryder for the simple reason that he/she is need of some points :-)

Comment: They're pretty much equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go :) :

```
lst = ["my name is Bob Jenkins", "Tommy Cooper I am", "I be Bazil", "I Tarzan"]
names = ["Bob", "Tarzan"]

new=[a for a in lst if all(x not in a for x in names) ]
print new
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use the `any` built in function:

```
newlst = [i for i in lst if not any(name in i for name in names)]
```

If you prefer, this expression using `all` is equivalent:

```
newlst = [i for i in lst if all(name not in i for name in names)]
```

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, `filter`:

```
filter(lambda s: not any(x in s for x in names),lst)
Out[4]: ['Tommy Cooper I am', 'I be Bazil']
```

For python 3, `list(filter)`:

```
list(filter(lambda s: not any(x in s for x in names),lst))
Out[4]: ['Tommy Cooper I am', 'I be Bazil']
```