# Find if any string element in list is contained in list of strings

Tags: python, list

I need to create a script to accept/reject some text based on whether a list of strings is present in it.

I have a list of keywords that should be used as a rejection mechanism:

```
k_out = ['word1', 'word2', 'some larger text']
```

If any of those string elements is found in the list I present below, the list should be marked as *rejected*. This is the list that should be checked:

```
c_lst = ['This is some text that contains no rejected word', 'This is some larger text which means this list should be rejected']
```

This is what I've got:

```
flag_r = False
for text in k_out:
    for lst in c_lst:
        if text in lst:
            flag_r = True
```

is there a more *pythonic* way of going about this?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python - Remove any element from a list of strings that is a substring of another element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21720199/python-remove-any-element-from-a-list-of-strings-that-is-a-substring-of-anothe)

Comment: It may be a duplicate, but it got a better answer than the other question.

Comment: When thinking about string containment, don't forget to ask yourself if you really want *string* containment or *word* containment: ask yourself whether `"name"` should reject `"enamel"`, etc.

Comment: @DSM that's a very good point because in fact _it shouldn't_. Would you expand a bit on the difference please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) and a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-generator_expression):

```
>>> k_out = ['word1', 'word2', 'some larger text']
>>> c_lst = ['This is some text that contains no rejected word', 'This is some larger text which means this list should be rejected']
>>> any(keyword in string for string in c_lst for keyword in k_out)
True
>>>
```

Comment: Does this really answer the question? The OP wants the list to be rejected if any of the words in the `k_out` list is found in the `c_lst`. The above code should have returned false if designed correctly

Comment: @Smac89 - It depends on how you interpret the question.  The OP said "If any of those **string elements** is found...the list should be marked as rejected".  I understood "string elements" to mean the substrings in `k_out`.   You'll notice too that my solution produces the same output as the OP's.  It is just a more compact way of doing it.

Comment: whoops I didn't see the full list because I was viewing this on my phone. Ok I see why this works now