# Remove a string that is a substring of other string in the list WITHOUT changing original order of the list?

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list.

```
the_list = ['Donald Trump has', 'Donald Trump has small fingers', 'What is going on?']
```

I'd like to remove "Donald Trump has" from `the_list` because it's a substring of other list element.

Here is an important part. I want to do this without distoring the order of the original list.

The function I have (below)  distorts the order of the original list. Because it sorts the list items by its length first.

```
def substr_sieve(list_of_strings):  
    dups_removed = list_of_strings[:]
    for i in xrange(len(list_of_strings)):
        list_of_strings.sort(key = lambda s: len(s))
        j=0
        j=i+1
        while j <= len(list_of_strings)-1:
            if list_of_strings[i] in list_of_strings[j]:
                try:
                    dups_removed.remove(list_of_strings[i])
                except:
                    pass
            j+=1
    return dups_removed
```

Comment: Why not make a second copy of the list to sort, then?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I already made a copy dups_removed. I think I'm not following you. How would that help?

Comment: I think you need to use the Divide And Conquer Paradigm

Comment: @ToussaintLouverture yes, but you're still sorting the original. So make *another* copy to sort.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21720199/python-remove-any-element-from-a-list-of-strings-that-is-a-substring-of-anothe seems similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this without sorting:

```
the_list = ['Donald Trump has', "I've heard Donald Trump has small fingers",
            'What is going on?']

def winnow(a_list):
    keep = set()
    for item in a_list:
        if not any(item in other for other in a_list if item != other):
            keep.add(item)
    return [ item for item in a_list if item in keep ]

winnow(the_list)
```

Sorting may allow fewer comparisons overall, but that seems highly data-dependent, and could be a premature optimization.

Comment: Elegant answer and it works (some of other answers don't work)

Comment: Doesn't it fail for this data set `the_list = ['Donald Trump', "Donald", "Trump", "Donald", "Donald Trump"]` or is that expected output ?

Comment: The OP didn't specify the expected output for that case.  My answer does keep all duplicates of the longest string.   This can be fixed by removing items from `keep` once they have been added to the result; the (slightly ugly) one-line version of that is: `return [ (keep.remove(item), item)[1] for item in a_list if item in keep ]`

Comment: It doesn't fail. ['Donald Trump', 'Donald Trump'] is the output

Answer (score 4):

A simple solution.

But first, let's also add '*Donald Trump*', *'Donald'* and *'Trump'* in the end to make it a better test case.

```
>>> forbidden_text = "\nX08y6\n" # choose a text that will hardly appear in any sensible string
>>> the_list = ['Donald Trump has', 'Donald Trump has small fingers', 'What is going on?',
        'Donald Trump', 'Donald', 'Trump']
>>> new_list = [item for item in the_list if forbidden_text.join(the_list).count(item) == 1]
>>> new_list
['Donald Trump has small fingers', 'What is going on?']
```

Logic:

1. Concatenate all list element to form a single string.
   **`forbidden_text.join(the_list)`.**
2. Search if an item in the list has occurred only once. If it occurs more than once it is a sub-string.**`count(item) == 1`**

> [str.count(sub[, start[, end]])](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.count)
>
> Return the number of non-overlapping occurrences of substring `sub` in the range `[start, end]`. Optional arguments `start` and `end` are interpreted as in slice notation.

---

`forbidden_text` is used instead of  `""` (blank string), to handle a case like these :

`>>> the_list = ['DonaldTrump', 'Donald', 'Trump']`

---

As correctly pointed by Nishant, above code fails for `the_list = ['Donald', 'Donald']`

Using a `set(the_list)` instead of `the_list` solves the problem.
`>>> new_list = [item for item in the_list if forbidden_text.join(set(the_list)).count(item) == 1]`

Comment: Does this work in this case `the_list = ['Donald Trump', 'Donald', 'Trump']`

Comment: This idea is very nice but I feel there are some corner cases to be handled. ['Donald', 'Donald'] is another one. But yeah it is a good alternative thinking.

Comment: Making it a set and then doing it will work I think.

Answer (score 0):

You can just recursively reduce the items.

Algorithm:

Loop over each item by popping it, decide if it needs to be kept or not.
Call the same function recursively with the reduced list.
Base condition is if the list has at-least one item (or two?).

Efficiency: It might not be the most efficient. I think some Divide and Conquer methods would be more apt?

```
the_list = ['Donald Trump has', 'Donald Trump has small fingers',\
            'What is going on?']

final_list = []

def remove_or_append(input):
    if len(input):
        first_value = input.pop(0)
        found = False
        for each in input:
            if first_value in each:
                found = True
                break
            else:
                continue
        for each in final_list:
            if first_value in each:
                found = True
                break
            else:
                continue
        if not found:
            final_list.append(first_value)
        remove_or_append(input)

remove_or_append(the_list)

print(final_list)
```

A slightly different version is:

```
def substring_of_anything_else(item, list):
    for idx, each in enumerate(list):
        if idx == item[0]:
            continue
        else:
            if item[1] in each:
                return True
        return False

final_list = [item for idx, item in enumerate(the_list)\ 
              if not substring_of_anything_else((idx, item), the_list)]
```

Comment: Has problems with Data set like ['Donald', 'Donald']