# How to use two loops to iterate a list in this case?

Tags: python

```
 list_back = l.copy
 for i, e in enumerate(l):
    j = i+1
    for j in range(len(l)):
        if e in l[j]:
            list_back.remove(e)
            return

l = ['a', 'bc', 'abc']
```

I want to check whether there is any element is a substring of another, if yes, then remove it. The 'l' is already sorted by string length.

In Java, j = i+1 works, but now Python. What' the equivalent?

Comment: [Python - Remove any element from a list of strings that is a substring of another element](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21720199/1324033)

Comment: Wait a minute. You are setting j variable and then you setting it in for loop with range, what's the point?

Comment: Use range(i+1,len(l)). Corrected typo. Thanks @Sayse for the remark